# How do I get my website to another server?

Tags: wordpress, webserver

My old server will be suspended and I will get another server. I have just WordPress on it. 
What do I need to do to make a perfect (without problems) switch to the new server?
What I already did is, saving all the data on the server via filezilla to my desktop.
And I exported my database via phpmyadmin.
What now?

Comment: There is also various questions and answers in various forms regarding moving a website from one host to another, from one domain to the next and how to move the SQL database.

Comment: there is no question about it in the "related" pane, and there was also no hint, when I created the question. Could you please tell me, how I could find one of these questions?